# ckeditor javascript code EditorInstance.document.getSelection().getStartElement() working on Firefox but Not Working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ckeditor, getselection

Node **JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```
Editor= CKEDITOR.instances['ckeditor1'];


getElem=Editor.document.getSelection().getStartElement();
getElem.setHtml("<Element6>SomeText</Element6>");
```

*Working On :* **FireFox**

*not working On :* **Internet Explorer**

The **Error** is :`'Editor.document.getSelection() **is null or not an object**

how do i get Parent node of cursor position in IE?

**DATA ON CKEDITOR:**

```
<Element1>SomeText<Element2>SomeText</Element2>
```

**`<Element3>Some**[suppose Cursor Is Here]** Text </Element3>`**

```
</Element1>
```

**Required Result:**

```
 <Element1>SomeText<Element2>SomeText</Element2><Element3>
```

**`<Element6>SomeText</Element6>`**

```
</Element3></Element1>
```

Comment: Focus editor (`editor.focus()`) and then get selection. If you know that editor is focused and you still can't get selection then you'd have to show us more code ((not) working example will be the best).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Following code Working well..** Thanks to * Reinmar*

```
Editor= CKEDITOR.instances['ckeditor1'];
Editor.focus();
getElem=Editor.document.getSelection().getStartElement();
getElem.setHtml("<Element6>SomeText</Element6>");
```